# How to run guetzli on all Jpeg images in a folder, and subfolders

Tags: batch-file, image-processing

I have just com across https://github.com/google/guetzli - And would like to write a script to run it on all jpeg images in a project on windows.

How would I loop though, all files in the folder and sub folder and get the relative paths to input into the command? Finally as guetzli is reasonably slow is there a way to wait for the execution to finish or put a delay in?

Thanks,
Lewis

Comment: See the hep on the `FOR` command to get a list of the files you need to process. You will need the `/R` option. Batch files only process one command at a time.  It does not execute the next command until the previous command is done executing.  There are some exceptions to that but that is the general rule of thumb. So your wait is most likely not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested, this is the code I went for;

```
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('forfiles /s /m *.jpg /c "cmd /c echo @relpath"') do 
(
  set "file=%%~A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  echo !file:~2!
  CALL "guetzli.exe" --quality 85 !file:~2! !file:~2!
  endlocal
)
```

Just put it into put it into the root directory with the guetzli executable

Comment: When I run this, it throws a syntax error in the for loop line.

Comment: It works now. I moved the opening parenthesis to the previous line along with `do` command. Somebody should modify the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to do this, and wrote these simple few lines of Python to handle it. No attempt here to be super-Pythonic. Only numeric jpgs is specific to the folder I was handling. Had to use quality=95 because of compression artifacts on very light skin tones still noticeable at 90. Still went from 6.4meg to 2.2meg for 25 420x280 jpg images (originals were max quality). At qual=85 size was 1.7meg, so 0.5meg for noticeable reduction in artifacts is acceptable. Stil big savings - Guetzli is great. HTH. -Steve

```
import os
import time
import subprocess

files = os.listdir('./')

jpgs = []
for file in files:
    if file[len(file)-3:] != 'jpg':
        continue
    try:
        fnum = int(file.split('.')[0])
    except:
        continue
    jpgs.append(file)
    jpgs.sort()


todo = len(jpgs)
done = 1
print '# %d = todo' % (todo)
start_tot = time.time()
for jpg in jpgs:
    fnum = int(jpg.split('.')[0])
    cmd = 'guetzli --quality 95 %d.jpg %d_g.jpg' % (fnum, fnum)
    print '# %d of %d' % (done, todo)
    print '# %s' % (cmd)
    start_img = time.time()
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
    t_this = time.time() - start_img
    t_tot = (time.time() - start_tot)
    avg = t_tot / float(done)
    done += 1
    print '#---%d done: %0.2f sec, %0.2f avgSec, %0.2f minTot' % ( fnum, t_this, avg, t_tot/60.0)
#end
```